# Exscript TimeoutException

Tags: python, ssh, cisco

So I finally got exscript working properly (I think). I wanted to test it, so I setup a simple python script I believe should work:

```
from Exscript.util.interact import read_login
from Exscript.protocols import SSH2

account = read_login()
conn = SSH2()
conn.connect('router.domain.com')
conn.login(account)

conn.execute('terminal length 0')

conn.execute('show version')
print conn.response

conn.send('exit\r')
conn.close()
```

I run the script and I'm presented with the following:

```
kidd@server scripts$ python test1.py
Please enter your user name [kidd]: 
Please enter your password:
```

It sits there for about 20 seconds, then I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 7, in <module>
    conn.login(account)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exscript/protocols/Protocol.py", line 597, in login
    self.auto_app_authorize(app_account, flush = flush)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exscript/protocols/Protocol.py", line 846, in auto_app_authorize
    self.get_driver().auto_authorize(self, account, flush, bailout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exscript/protocols/drivers/one_os.py", line 43, in auto_authorize
    conn.app_authorize(account, flush, bailout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exscript/protocols/Protocol.py", line 820, in app_authorize
    self._app_authenticate(account, password, flush, bailout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exscript/protocols/Protocol.py", line 690, in _app_authenticate
    raise TimeoutException(msg)
Exscript.protocols.Exception.TimeoutException: Buffer: '\rThis is a private system \r\n \r\nrouter>'
```

Am I missing something simple? Just trying to login to a router (as a normal user, non-privilege mode), run a show version, then log out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the banner you have configured is messing with the prompt that Exscript is expecting back from the device. I'd suggest either tweaking the protocol driver within Exscript to handle the prompt better, or making sure your banner is set up properly (or removing it all together)